# No sound from laptop speakers

Tags: windows-10, speakers

A few months ago the builtin speakers on my Lenovo thinkpad (running Windows 10) stopped producing sound. I've tried the following:

- Checking they are unmuted and setting volume to maximum
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the device in device manager
- Switching to the "High Definition Audio Device" driver
- Asking Windows to automatically select a driver (Conexant SmartAudio HD)
- Installing a driver from Lenovo's website
- In device settings, checking they are enabled and disabling any advanced features (eg Dolby Audio)
- Testing the same speakers while running Linux (works fine)
- Testing headphones while running Windows (works fine)

What else should I try? So far I've just been blindly trying things that I've read about; I'm especially interested in anything I can do to get more insight into the problem (eg if the driver is logging errors somewhere).

Comment: Did you check if the internal speakers are selected as the audio output device? In the configuration screen, go to System → Sound. The output device could for instance be set to a connected monitor, or to the headphones.

Comment: @Berend thanks but no luck, it's set to "Speakers (Conexant SmartAudio HD)", which is the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be related to having Ubuntu installed alongside Windows; **when I muted in Ubuntu, and then switched to Windows, the speakers were silent** despite all Windows settings indicating otherwise. To fix the problem, I just needed to **unmute in Ubuntu and switch back to Windows**.

My hypothesis is that Ubuntu is toggling some flag on the sound hardware when I mute/unmute, but Windows isn't touching that flag.